# How to create the trigger for the table in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [RTS].[MFB]
(
    [record_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [marker_id] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [lat] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [lng] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [address] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
    [hash] [smallint] NULL,
    [updated] [datetime] NULL,
    [first_created_date] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_MFB_1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([record_id] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

where the "record_id" is the primary key.

I need to create a trigger after the `INSERT` operation.

The conditions are:

1. If the `marker_id` column is new, `INSERT` the record to the table and set the `hash` column to 0;
2. If the `marker_id` already exists, `UPDATE` the existing record by setting the new `updated` column;
3. If both the `marker_id` already exists and any of the "lat", "lng" and "address" has been changed, `UPDATE` the existing record by setting the new "lat", "lng" and/or "address" and also setting "hash" to "1".

Basically, the MFB table should not have duplicated `marker_id`.

How can I achieve this by a setting up a trigger? Thanks!

Comment: You can't handle whether to insert or update through trigger because it will trigger after inserting, updating & deleting. You can do it for another table (good example is `LOG` table) based on the event on this table.

Comment: I suggest you do not use a trigger. I suggest you create a unique index on the `marker_id` column and make sure changes to this table only occur through a stored procedure that enforces these business rules. Regardless, you need to show what you've already tried - no one will write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafal is right but you can make a cursor for bulk insert and update but i cant promise for performance it should be like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER DBO.MFBTRG 
   ON  DBO.MFB 
   INSTEAD OF INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @marker_id NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @lat NUMERIC(38,8)
DECLARE @lng NUMERIC(38,8)
DECLARE @address NVARCHAR(512)
DECLARE @hash SMALLINT
DECLARE @updated DATETIME
DECLARE @first_created_date DATETIME
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE MFBINS CURSOR  FAST_FORWARD FOR  Select [marker_id],[lat],[lng],[address],[hash],[updated],[first_created_date] FROM INSERTED
OPEN MFBINS 
FETCH NEXT FROM MFBINS INTO @marker_id,@lat,@lng,@address,@hash,@updated,@first_created_date
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
        BEGIN

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [marker_id] FROM MFB WHERE [marker_id]= @marker_id)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MFB] ([marker_id],[lat],[lng],[address],[hash],[updated],[first_created_date])
           VALUES (@marker_id,@lat,@lng,@address,@hash,@updated,@first_created_date)
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
UPDATE MFB SET [updated]=@updated WHERE [marker_id]=@marker_id
END 


    -- Insert statements for trigger here
FETCH NEXT FROM MFBINS INTO @marker_id,@lat,@lng,@address,@hash,@updated,@first_created_date
END
CLOSE MFBINS
DEALLOCATE MFBINS
END
GO
```

and you can use to detect which column is update on update trigger with

```
IF UPDATE(COLUMN_NAME)
BEGIN
UPDATE LOGİC
END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it this way you would have to create INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger - but beware it is going to be slow as you wouldn't be able to benefit from bulk insert.

Alternatively you could use [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement and perform your INSERT/UPDATE scenario there.